# Mock de classe sem métodos

Tags: python, mock

Preciso mockar uma classe que não possui métodos e não retorna nada, como eu poderia fazer isso em Python? Estou mockando essa classe porque ela atua como conversora de tipagem.

A minha classe é bem parecida com essa abaixo:

```
class ClasseExemplo(OutraClasseExemplo):
    item_1: str
    item_2: datetime
    item_3: int
    item_4: datetime
    item_5: str
```

E já tentei algumas alternativas que não funcionaram:

```
@patch.object(ClasseExemplo)
@patch('caminho.caminho.arquivo_onde_a_classe_se_encontra')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sem você dar mais detalhes, tudo que é possível adiantar é que você provavelmente *não precisa*  mockar uma classe desse tipo.

SImplesmente deixe o código que vai usar essa classe usar a classe original.

Por que há 4 coisas que seu código e testes podem requerer do Mock:

(1) querer que a classe exista, de forma que o código funcione: o código vai funcionar se for a classe original e não um mock

(2) querer escrever atributos e chamar métodos na classe, e no teste, você querer verificar se os atributos forem escritos corretamente: como não há métodos, você não precisa das funcionalidades do mock para verificar quais chamadas foram feitas e com quais parâmetros. Já atributos escritos vão funcionar tão bem com  a classe como ela está, como com um mock, então o mock não é necessário

(3) O código alvo vai ler atributos e anotações na classe e usar isso internamente: novamente, não só isso vai funcionar perfeitamente com a classe original, como daria algum trabalho recriar a classe e as anotações usando os mocks do Python.  O mock não só não é necessário como seria bem trabalhoso.

(4) o código a ser testado vai chamar métodos no código mocado que vão causar efeitos colaterais de entrada e saída (gravação de arquivos/envio ou recebimento de informações na rede -; criação de objetos no banco de dados)  - e o uso do Mock permite exercitar esse código sem desencadear esses efeitos colaterais. De novo: se a classe não tem código, também não tem efetos colaterais perigosos.

---

Consigo imaginar que você queira passar uma classe com anotações diferentes das da classe original para o código a ser testado - nesse caso, se usa sim a chamada `unittest.mock.patch`, mas com um argumento `new` específico, não para um mock.

Nesse caso, você primeiro declara a classe substituta (pode ser dentro do código da função de teste, ou no próprio módulo de teste - tanto faz), e usa, como uma string, o caminho completo da classe que quer mocar, incluindo os pacotes, subpacotes, módulo (arquivo) *e* o nome da classe, serparados por ponto:

```py
class ExemploSubstituto:
    item_1: str


with unitest.mock.patch(
    "meuprojeto.arquivo_de_classe.ClasseExemplo",
     new=ExemploSubstituto):
   # código que chama as classes que usam o "ClasseExemplo"
```

Uma outra coisa, se o arquivo que usa a "ClasseExemplo" importa a mesma fazendo isso:

arquivo_que_usa.py

```py
from arquivo_de_classe import ClasseExemplo
...
```

Uma outra coisa: não adianta alterar a ClasseExemplo no "arquivo_de_classe" - a ClasseExemplo no "arquivo_que_usa" vai continuar apontando para o objeto anterior.

Nesses casos, o mais recomendado é que o código seja desta forma:

```py
import arquivo_de_classe 

...
def alguma_funcao():
    ...
    instancia = arquivo_de_classe.ClasseExemplo()
    ...
```

Mas você também pode fazer o patch direto no "arquivo_que_usa" - também
vai funcionar - mas se o código ali, chamar código em um terceiro arquivo
que também acesse a classe, cada um vai ver uma classe diferente - então não é 
recomendado. Nesse caso específico, o melhor mesmo é ver se você realmente vai
precisar mockar essas classes.